# How to find Azure Build Items for a specific repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-apps

I am trying to fetch the list of all build items in Azure, and using Postman the following URL shows me the result:

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0
```

But there is one problem, the query shows me the build for all our company projects whereas I am only intersted in one

[image]

The query returns for all projects, but I am only interested in build for Project B

How can I specify this information in the API? I tried the filters and it doesn't work.
Also the same for tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [API Build List documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), you can see the optional parameters that can be passed to this request

In this case, you would want to filter on builds from the project B repository, which requires the repositoryType parameter to be passed as well. As such you'd be looking to call

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryID={repoID}&repositoryType=Git&api-version=6.0
```

Where the repoID can be found be going into project settings-->repository, clicking the project B repo and copying the value that appears in the website URL after repo=

Comment: Hi, I don't see the param `RepositoryID` in devops. I only get a url like this: `https://dev.azure.com/foo/bar/_settings/repositories?repo=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx` do you think the URL is updated?

Comment: Hello, so the xxxx part of the url would be the repository ID

Comment: Hi, I am still checking .. i don't think the repo=xxx fixes the issue ... will check again and accept if the issue is from my side

Comment: Good luck, hope it solves it. It definitely works for me to filter down to builds from a specific repo so should work for you

Answer (score 1):

1. As Davis wrote above, use shared API, but remove from it repositoryId parameter, as Azure DevOps fails to use it as filter criteria. I have exactly the same problem.
   Updated API endpoint is the below.
2. Then you need to search for repositoryId in received response and you will get build details.

Valid URL for API calls:
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryType=Git&api-version=6.0`

When build was triggered by your code change then you can try to add requested For query parameter. Then API URL looks as follows:
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryType=Git&requestedFor={yourIdentity}&api-version=6.0`